# Problem with differentiability of function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, continuity, differential

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. Consider the function $f$ defined by
$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
e^{-\frac{1}{x}}+\sqrt{1+2x}\ \ &\mbox{ if }\ \ x>0,\\
a\ \ &\mbox{ if }\ \ x=0,\\
b\sin(x)+1\ \ &\mbox{ if }\ \ x<0.
\end{array}
\right.
$$

$1)$ Determine the value of $a$ so that $f$ is continuous at $x=0$. ($a=1$)

$2)$ For this value of $a$, determine $b$ so that $f$ is
differentiable at $x=0$.

I want to ask, is there a problem with this exercise? More precisely part 2, because I think one cannot find $b$.

Comment: At a first sight, I find no problem with this question.

Comment: Are you sure about the fact it is divergent? Use $\sqrt{1+h} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}h + o(h^2)$ as $h\to 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, $a=1$ is the answer to part $1)$. For part $2$, we have

$$f'(x)= \begin{cases} 
          \frac{e^{-1/x}}{x^2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 x+1}} & x> 0 \\
          b \cos(x) & x<0 
       \end{cases}$$

What we want is these two directions to connect at $x=0$. We have that

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f'(x)=1$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}f'(x)=b$$

Thus, if we set $b=1$ then

$$\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)=1$$

and we are done.

Comment: This is using the fact that a function $f$ which is $C^1$ on $\Bbb R^*$ such that $f'$ has equal limits from the right and from the left at $0$ is $C^1$, which is a bit stronger than what the exercise is asking. In my opinion, the spirit of the exercise is to use the definition of the derivative as a limit of a quotient at $0$n without refering to others points or the continuity of the derivative

Comment: @Student No it is not!

Comment: @Didier Good point, I guess it depends on what OP is allowed to utilize for this exercise